# What is the file format of Objective C?

Tags: visual-studio-code, programming-languages

I was testing programming language file formats and checking if they exist in Visual Studio Code, but then I saw that there was an Objective C programming language, and I was searching everywhere for the file format, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commonly, `.mm`, `.m`, but also `.h`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: .mm is Objective C++, .m is Objective C, and .h is Header. (Don't get these wrong next time!)